# How would I add a validation check to this code?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have this code to check for an ID number and thereafter copy the row in which the ID is located into another spreadsheet. If the ID number that is input in the userform does not exist I want there to be an error message that prompts you to try again and that also cancels all of the code that is executed when the ID number that has been input exists

I have tried a simple If statement but did not get it to work

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Set wsSource = Sheets("Arkiv")
Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
Set wsDestination = Sheets("DN")

Dim IDnum As String
IDnum = TextBox1.Text

Dim idRow As Long
idRow = wsSource.Columns("A:A").Find(what:=IDnum, lookat:=xlWhole).Row

Dim SourceAdresses() As Variant
SourceAdresses = Array("B" & idRow, "C" & idRow, "D" & idRow, "E" & idRow, "F" & idRow, "G" & idRow, "H" & idRow, "I" & idRow)

Dim DestinationAdresses() As Variant
DestinationAdresses = Array("D9", "E9", "I9", "C20", "D20", "E45", "g20", "H20", "I20")

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(SourceAdresses) To UBound(SourceAdresses)
    wsDestination.Range(DestinationAdresses(i)).Value = wsSource.Range(SourceAdresses(i)).Value
Next i

wsDestination.Activate
Unload Me
MsgBox "Data is now available"

End Sub
```

I expect the user form to prompt an "Error, ID was not found/does not exist in the archive" message and cancel all following code from being executed and there after let you retry typing an ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of your entire process, but the below code (not tested) should be able to give you SOME idea what you need to do to create this error handling. Effectively, using a `For` loop will do this...

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Set wsSource = Sheets("Arkiv")
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Set wsDestination = Sheets("DN")

    Dim IDnum As String
    Dim idRow As Long
    Dim SourceAdresses() As Variant
    Dim DestinationAdresses() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For j = 1 To 5

        IDnum = TextBox1.Text
        idRow = wsSource.Columns("A:A").Find(what:=IDnum, lookat:=xlWhole).Row

        If idRow = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Error finding ID number! Please try again!"
        Else
            Exit For
        End If

        If j = 5 Then
            'number of attempts exceeded - end program
            MsgBox "Could not locate the ID number! Closing program.."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next j

    SourceAdresses = Array("B" & idRow, "C" & idRow, "D" & idRow, "E" & idRow, "F" & idRow, "G" & idRow, "H" & idRow, "I" & idRow)
    DestinationAdresses = Array("D9", "E9", "I9", "C20", "D20", "E45", "G20", "H20", "I20")

    For i = LBound(SourceAdresses) To UBound(SourceAdresses)
        wsDestination.Range(DestinationAdresses(i)).Value = wsSource.Range(SourceAdresses(i)).Value
    Next i

    wsDestination.Activate

    Unload Me
    MsgBox "Data is now available"

End Sub
```

Comment: Gives me the error that ìdRow` is not set in the line                                          `idRow = wsSource.Columns("A:A").Find(what:=IDnum, lookat:=xlWhole).Row`                                 Don't know why since it's clearly declared as a `Long` above?

Comment: ntw my first ID is in A2 and continues downwards incrementing by 1 each time if that is necessary information.

Comment: That would imply that the ID was not found. There are two ways to approach. A) Because we are expecting an error here when the ID is not found you can add `On Error Resume Next` above `idRow = ...` or B) we could use a different error handler in the sense of `On Error GoTo myErrHandler` where you declare `myErrHandler:` and then have a similar procedure to handle.

Comment: how would I not have to go through the loop 5 times when i input a non-existing ID? `On error resume next...` something?

Comment: The loop gives the user a certain amount of tries to insert a valid ID (in the example above, 5). In the event that the user fails to insert a valid ID within this limit it closed the program. If there is a match with the ID, it uses `Exit For` to exit the `For` loop. In the event you want to exit with a non-existing ID, use this same method of `Exit For`. Not sure on the utility of that though!

Comment: This was very confusing to me sorry, I can't seem to figure out how to go about using those tips...

Comment: @SanderJensen you need to incorporate the above logic into how the user selects/ inputs an ID. As such once they make a select you need to run a `For` loop on that to handle the potential for mismatching. Sorry bud, not sure how else I can explain this without knowing your complete A-Z